# Parse JS value into MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a script that keeps track of certain images positions by updating a variable in Javascript. However I need to parse that value to the DB in order to make the object stay the same place next time a user logs in. My JS code is below: (house_positions.js)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").draggable({
containment: '#house_wall1',

drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },

// Find original position of dragged image.
start: function(event, ui) {

    // Show start dragged position of image.
    var Startpos = $(this).position();
    $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
},

// Find position where image is dropped.
stop: function(event, ui) {

    // Show dropped position.
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);

}
});
});
```

And then I have my MySQL database call:

```
<?php
        require_once('x'); // don't mind the connection

                    window.newX = $_POST['newx'];
        window.newY = $_POST['newy'];

            /* Register a prepared statement */
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = newX, y =  newY WHERE `user_id`=?')) { 

                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $id = 1;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
            }
?>
```

As you can see, I have tried inserting the "xPos" variable from Javascript, into the MySQL statement in PHP. I did not believe this would work, but well. Can anyone tell me how this is possible? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
My Ajax code:

```
function houseAjax()
            {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                $.post("update_house.php.asp",{window.newx: xPos, window.newy: yPos},function(result){

                  });
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","update_house.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

Comment: have you ever heard about 'AJAX' ?

Comment: Yes the database call gets called with ajax but I am still not sure how to parse it into the database?

Comment: @samitha I have posted my Ajax code if that helps

Comment: you cant simply get xpos value like that in query

Answer (score 0):

You doing it bit wrong, When calling the php function that update your DB you must transfer your parameters from the javascript code to your PHP. as before you'd do that your php wont know it.

Java script example:

```
$.post("http://www.pbpixels.com/x/update_house.php",{newx:xPos, newy: yPos},function(result){
    //data is updated
  });
```

Wherever you catch the ajax request in your server side php page just get it from the call:

PHP:

```
newX = $_POST['newx'];
newY = $_POST['newy'];
```

and now call the update function:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = newX, y = newY 
                                                           WHERE `user_id`=?'))
```

Anyhow, I would recommend you to extend your Ajax knowledge by doing [some reading](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Good Luck

Comment: So perhaps something like above? Can I put your javascript example inside the ajax function?

Comment: Yeah just make sure X and Y are global variables, and remove the second ajax call

Comment: Okay I updated the UPDATE statement to something that looks more correctly, what do I need to do now? What ajax call do you want me to remove and what X and Y global variables?

Comment: this is my best bet yet. Can you see what I'm missing? I've tried adding global variables but I am really unsure if it is correct. Thanks

Comment: to make xPos a global var just declare it outside of any function scope: "var xPos = 0" and then change it in the function like this "xPos = offset.left;"

Comment: uhm one problem is that if I do so, the images can't be moved around, they're stuck at their positions. And even if I make them global, nothing happens with the database.

Comment: i need to see more information. and please vote for the answer if that assist you so far